# python compare two dict containing list and get only the difference

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to compare two dict and get only the difference between dict_one, dict_two and to get dict_three

```
dict_one = {'AAA': ['toto', 'tata'], 'BBB': ['toto', 'tyty'], 'CCC': ['tete', 'toto']}
dict_two = {'AAA': ['toto', 'titi'], 'BBB': ['toto', 'titi', 'tyty']}

dict_three = {'AAA': ['tata', 'titi'], 'BBB': ['titi'], 'CCC': ['tete', 'toto']}
```

I have a code but I get all value :

```
list_one = list(dict_one.keys())
list_two = list(dict_two.keys())
common_keys = set(list_one) - (set(list_one) - set(list_two))

for key in common_keys:
    if dict_one[key] != dict_two[key]:
        print("Value key is : " + key + ":" + str(dict_two[key]) + " should be like in dict_one : " + str(dict_one[key]))
```

but I want ot get dict_three

Comment: Lists are ordered and can contain duplicates. In some of the cases you provided, the lists for the same key (e.g. `BBB`) are of different length. How would you compare them? What if the two lists had the same items, but in a different order (e.g. `['toto', 'titi']` vs `['titi', 'toto']`?

Comment: Why for key `'CCC'` values that are common in both `dicts` present while for key `'BBB'` they are not

Comment: Sorry, I forget to remove it

Answer (score 1):

Use symmetric difference of sets

```
d=dict()
commmon_keys=set(dict_one.keys()).union(set(dict_two.keys()))
for k in commmon_keys:
    d[k] = list(set(dict_one.get(k,[])) ^ set(dict_two.get(k,[])))
```

Output:

```
{'AAA': ['tata', 'titi'], 'BBB': ['titi'], 'CCC': ['tete', 'toto']}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget to delete (key, value)for C key in dict_two

Comment: @locklmm Then also above code should work only output will differ then if you change the intersection to union.Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a union of the keys of the two dicts and get the symmetric difference of the dict values of the given keys:

```
{k: list(set(dict_one.get(k, [])).symmetric_difference(dict_two.get(k, []))) for k in dict_one.keys() | dict_two.keys()}
```

This returns:

```
{'CCC': ['toto', 'tete'], 'AAA': ['titi', 'tata'], 'BBB': ['titi']}
```